# Regular Expressions find/replace

Tags: search, notepad++, regex, notepad, find-and-replace

How to I do a search for @anydomain.anyTLD using regular expressions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@[a-zA-Z0-0\-]*\.[a-zA-Z\.]*`

You could improve that but I don't think n++ deals with more complicated regex patterns.

Ideally we'd just use something like

`/@[a-z0-9\-]\.[a-z\.\-]{1,40}/i`

Which supports everything from [the iana TLD list](http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt) But N++ doesn't support that.

And if we want to get fancy we could do

`(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])`

Which supports RFC2822 (see [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) for more details)

Comment: `.co.uk` would like to speak to you, it's 4 characters. I've found that exact regex matching is often far more trouble than it's worth - for example with http://to/. A more exact regex might miss it, but I was using `(https?://[^\s]*)`, a much more general expression, and it worked fine.

Comment: You are most correct, I have changed the above to work with websites such as .co.uk.

Comment: @user25866: That wasn't my point. How about `.org.uk`? Indeed, the current technical maximum for a tld is *64 characters*, and http://to/ **is** the TLD! +1 for a correct answer, but your "ideal" regex is far from it.

Comment: Added one that gets real fancy.